# fallback aliased directory for static files that don't exist

Tags: mod-rewrite, ibmhttpserver

Current configuration:

```
Alias   /wcsstore       "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/demo/installedApps/WC_demo_cell/WC_demo.ear/Stores.war"
```

Example URL:

```
http://okdemo/wcsstore/test.txt
```

How do I make it first look for existing file `/opt/IBM/test/test.txt` and use the original directory as fallback?

Tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/wcsstore/(.*) /wcsstore-old/$1 [PT,L]

Alias   /wcsstore       "/opt/IBM/test"
Alias   /wcsstore-old       "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/demo/installedApps/WC_demo_cell/WC_demo.ear/Stores.war"
```

But it seems that `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not resolve to `/opt/IBM/test/test.txt`. Everything is served from the fallback dir:

```
RewriteCond: input='/wcsstore/test.txt' pattern='!-f' => matched
```

Maybe I should concatenate: `/opt/IBM/test%{REQUEST_URI}` , but how to remove the `/wcsstore` word before concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In virtualhost context REQUEST_FILENAME is just the same as the request URL, since nothing has been mapped yet.  You could prefix with %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ to poke around, or any other explicit path.

To remove "wcstore", use a rewriteCond to split the string and then use %1 instead of the original variable

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wcsstore/(.*)
RewriteRule /var/www/.../%1 ! -f
```